# Finding product of values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Write a function called productOfValues which takes in an object of key/value pairs and multiplies the values together. You can assume that all keys are strings and all values are integers.

For example:

```
let testObject = {
  'a': 5, 
  'b': 12,
  'c': 3
}

productOfValues(testObject)
```

So, this is what I wrote:

```js
let testObject = {
  'a': 5,
  'b': 12,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 1
}
let testObject_v = {
  'z': 2,
  'y': 2,
  'x': 2,
  'w': 2
}

function productOfValues(someObject) {
  return someObject.a * someObject.b * someObject.c;
}

function productOfValues(testObject) {
  return testObject_v.z * testObject_v.y * testObject_v.x * testObject_v.w;
}

console.log(productOfValues(testObject))
console.log(productOfValues(testObject_v))
```

And I've got an error of:

> Your productOfValues function should return the product of the values in the given object: 180

Comment: Use `Object.values()` to get the numbers (the values) from your object. Then loop over this array of numbers and multiply them

Comment: Why do you implement  `function productOfValues` 2 time?

Comment: it was just a question because I believe function overloading isnt supported in Javascript, looking for a way to do it @RGhanbari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining the same function twice and you're only multiplying the first 3 numbers in the first object.  Instead, rewrite your `productOfValues()` function to be something like this:

```js
let testObject = {
  'a': 5,
  'b': 12,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 1
}
let testObject_v = {
  'z': 2,
  'y': 2,
  'x': 2,
  'w': 2
}

function productOfValues(someObject) {
  let product = 1;
  for (const i in someObject) {
    product = product * someObject[i];
  }
  return product;
}

console.log(productOfValues(testObject))
console.log(productOfValues(testObject_v))
```

**Edit:**
Alternative `productOfValues()` function:

```
function productOfValues(someObject) {
  var result = 1; 
  var len = Object.keys(someObject).length; 
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {     
    result = result * someObject[Object.keys(someObject)[i]]; 
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why can't I use: var result = 1;
  var len = arguments.length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
                result = result * arguments[i];  
            }

Comment: @JMNav Because your argument is an object, so it doesn't have a `length` property. You can do it this way, but you'll have to get the list of keys using `Object.keys(argument).length`.  I'll update my answer with an example for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Object.values` to convert your object to array of its values & then use `reduce` to get the product of that values array

```js
let testObject = {'a': 5,'b': 12,'c': 3, 'd':1};
let testObject_v = { 'z':2,'y':2,'x':2,'w':2 }

function productOfValues(someObject) {
  return Object.values(someObject).reduce((a,b)=> a*b ,1);
}

console.log(productOfValues(testObject));
console.log(productOfValues(testObject_v));
```

Comment: @Jirah Marie Navarro Please look at this solution & mark it as accepted if it solves your issue